# Java Code to interect with Active Directory

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, jndi

I need to write a Java code which can add /update / search a user from the Active Directory. I was looking on the web for any JAVA API and find some of the open source API's. 
Can someone please guide me to the right directions or tell me how to start with this?

Comment: You could approach it as an LDAP?

Comment: [See here](http://myjeeva.com/querying-active-directory-using-java.html).  It was literally the first thing I found searching for "active directory java" in google.

Answer (score 0):

We have used [UNBOUNDID](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/) (and think they have the best SDK for LDAP) includes some special features for Microsoft Active Directory.